# How can you prove that a collection of union set is equal to the set of natural numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

For example $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n=\mathbb{N}$

My proof, 
to prove that two sets are equal i must show that they are subsets of each other. I understand how to show $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ but i get stuck with with the other way to show that $\mathbb{N}\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n$

My proof for that is, given an element $x\in\mathbb{N}$ 
since $A_x\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ then $x\in A_x$ and means that $x\in\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$

please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: $x\in \mathbb N $ and $A_x\subseteq\mathbb N$ does not imply $x\in A_x$.

Comment: It would help to say what the $A_n$ are.

Comment: Usually you find a procedure so that if I give you $m$, you can find some $A_n$ that it belongs to.  That depends on how the $A_n$ are defined.

Comment: You, please, mention mention at the beginning that the sets consist of natural numbers.

Comment: Oh actually i think i understand, sorry for not showing the $A_n,A_n= {n,n+1,n+2,n+3} $ , so $A_n\in\mathbb{N}$ then $x\in {n,n+1,n+2,n+3}$ therefore x is in the union